# Installing Qt on Yocto

Tags: qt, qtembedded

I am working on a project contains, “Renesis R-Car H2 board” with Yocto installed in it. I am trying to find a proper way to install Qt in Yocto. Actually my application is running very slow in Yocto. I think it’s because of wrong Qt configuration. It would be very much appreciated if someone could help me to solve this problem.

Regards
Ansif

Answer (score 0):

https://elinux.org/R-Car/Boards/Yocto

Refer to 'Adding Qt5 in Yocto image'

If you try to run example applications, after successful build you must be able to run Qt5 examples on target:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libEGL.so
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/root
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland-egl
/usr/share/qt5/examples/opengl/cube/cube
```